# Pandas to_dict() Returning "Timestamp"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well this is embarrassing... I'm trying to create a [good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) by giving you guys a small sample of my dataset. I thought this would be simple with `df.to_dict()` but to no avail.

```
df2 = df1[['DATE_FILLED','DAYS_SUPPLY']].head(5)
df2['DATE_FILLED'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE_FILLED'])
diction = df2.to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'DATE_FILLED': {0: Timestamp('2016-12-28 00:00:00'),
                 1: Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'), 
                 2: Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), 
                 3: Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), 
                 4: Timestamp('2016-12-26 00:00:00')}, 
     'DAYS_SUPPLY': {0: 14, 1: 14, 2: 14, 3: 7, 4: 7}}
```

But if the community were to convert it to a dataframe by using the text:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
d= pd.DataFrame({'DATE_FILLED': [Timestamp('2016-12-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-26 00:00:00')], 'DAYS_SUPPLY': [14, 14, 14, 7, 7]})
```

They would get `NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined`.
I've tried importing various things and even tried playing around with the different `orients` in [`pd.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

How do I either convert the `Timestamps` or better yet, create a DataFrame from them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to import `Timestamp` from `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pandas import Timestamp
>>> d= pd.DataFrame({'DATE_FILLED': [Timestamp('2016-12-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-12-26 00:00:00')], 'DAYS_SUPPLY': [14, 14, 14, 7, 7]})
>>>
>>> d
  DATE_FILLED  DAYS_SUPPLY
0  2016-12-28           14
1  2016-12-31           14
2  2016-12-20           14
3  2016-12-21            7
4  2016-12-26            7
>>>
```

In the future, you can always use introspection to give you a good hint:

```
>>> ts = d.to_dict()['DATE_FILLED'][0]
>>> type(ts)
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
>>> from pandas.tslib import Timestamp
```

Comment: Wat if there is multiple key has timestramp?

Answer (score 9):

You just need to import Timestamp:

```
from pandas import Timestamp

d = {'DATE_FILLED': {0: Timestamp('2016-12-28 00:00:00'),
                 1: Timestamp('2016-12-31 00:00:00'), 
                 2: Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), 
                 3: Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), 
                 4: Timestamp('2016-12-26 00:00:00')}, 
     'DAYS_SUPPLY': {0: 14, 1: 14, 2: 14, 3: 7, 4: 7}}



pd.DataFrame(d)
Out: 
  DATE_FILLED  DAYS_SUPPLY
0  2016-12-28           14
1  2016-12-31           14
2  2016-12-20           14
3  2016-12-21            7
4  2016-12-26            7
```

Comment: Beat me by 17 seconds!

Comment: Instead of a third answer with identical content... I'll stick to upvoting ;-)  Nice to see you answering questions.

Comment: I knew it was this simple... Couldn't find that in the docs *anywhere*

Comment: @ayhan yeah, I've encountered this issue in very similar circumstances!

Comment: I kid you not... I still can't find it even knowing what to search for. Dare i go to ask.com...? Can anyone find the documentation on this?

Comment: @MattR check out my answer for how you could have discovered this easily yourself by checking the `type` object

Answer (score 2):

`import module` doesn't enter the module's names into the global namespace, you have to access them via `module.name`. To enter the module's names into the global namespace, you need to use the `from module import` syntax. In this case, either `from pandas import Timestamps`, which enters `Timestamps` into the global namespace, or `from pandas import *`, which imports all of the names in pandas into the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This will certainly help in the future